# seeded record with integer array value always nil even when passing values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- Ruby version
  ruby 3.2.0
- Rails version
  rails 7.0.5

I have a model called `Box`.
Here is the controller for that model:

```rb
class BoxesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_box, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /boxes or /boxes.json
  def index
    @boxes = Box.all
  end

  # GET /boxes/1 or /boxes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /boxes/new
  def new
    @box = Box.new
  end

  # GET /boxes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /boxes or /boxes.json
  def create
    @box = Box.new(box_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @box.save
        format.html { redirect_to box_url(@box), notice: "Box was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @box }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @box.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /boxes/1 or /boxes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @box.update(box_params)
        format.html { redirect_to box_url(@box), notice: "Box was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @box }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @box.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /boxes/1 or /boxes/1.json
  def destroy
    @box.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to boxes_url, notice: "Box was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_box
      @box = Box.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def box_params
      params.require(:box).permit(:sessions)
    end
end
```

Here is the schema for the boxes table in `db/schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "boxes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "sessions", array: true, default: []
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name", uniq: true, null: false
  end
```

However, when I run `rails db:seed` using the following `db/seeds.rb` file, all `Box` records have `sessions: nil`.

```rb
Box.create([
             {sessions: [], name: 'Current'},
             {sessions: [], name: 'Retired'},
             {sessions: [0,2,5,9], name: 'Box 1'},
             {sessions: [1,3,6,0], name: 'Box 2'},
             {sessions: [2,4,7,1], name: 'Box 3'},
             {sessions: [3,5,8,2], name: 'Box 4'},
             {sessions: [4,6,9,3], name: 'Box 5'},
             {sessions: [5,7,0,4], name: 'Box 6'},
             {sessions: [6,8,1,5], name: 'Box 7'},
             {sessions: [7,9,2,6], name: 'Box 8'},
             {sessions: [8,0,3,7], name: 'Box 9'},
             {sessions: [9,1,4,8], name: 'Box 10'}
           ])
```

When running `Box.create(sessions:[1,2,3,4], name: 'testbox')` in rails console, the result is the same.
What am I doing wrong to create a this property with an integer array?

I would expect that adding the default value would at least result in some records with `sessions: []` but that has not worked either.

Comment: What type of DB? Postgres, MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Your `sessions` are not a single value, but an array of values. Therefore, you have to permit this attribute to be an array in your strong params method, like this:

```
def box_params
  params.require(:box).permit(:name, sessions: [])
end
```

Comment: When making that change, I still have `sessions: nil` on every Box after seeding.

Comment: I suggest changing `save`to `save!` (or `create` to `create!` or `update` to `update!` – what ever method you use for testing). Because that would raise an error instead of simply returning `false` when saving was unsuccessful. The error message of the raise exception will likely tell you what is missing. If that doesn't help, then please share your `Box` model and the log entries when you try to create a record.